# Determine these two angle (Isosceles triangle)

Tags: geometry

Please see the following diagram:

[image] 
This is an isosceles triangle.

Let the angles be as follow: green = G, red = R, blue = B, purple = P

G = pi - 2B

Now my question is.. Based on the value of blue angle (B)- is it possible to determine the R and P angles given the radius and arc length. The angles are formed by the tangent of the circles at the intersection point [image: angle]

Arc length is the "outside" arc length, for example, for the bottom right circle, it goes from point G to point H. Radius is simple-

All circles have the same radius, R1=R2=R3. As for the arc length, I believe the two bottom circles have the same L1=L2, but the upper circles's will be different.

I tried working it out, I obtained the value for the purple angle to be : 2pi - L/R; Can someone verify this as well? I am mostly interested in the red angle.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you adapt [my answer to your previous post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/855241/35416) to this situation? You know the interior angles, so you know the exterior ones as well, and with $\frac LR$ you also know how much is covered by the circle. The rest should be simple.

Comment: @MvG Can you help me with a diagram? your previous answer's was easy to read for me (I am a visual learner) but I am not very good at drawing just yet. I will try to figure out the rest myself! Thx

Comment: It's not as easy as I thought at first: I incorrectly assumed that the angle bisectors as $A$ and $B$ would bisect the outer arc $L$, but that's not the case. Perhaps a reasonable first step would be working out how large the circles are with respect to the triangle. The ratio $L/R$ encodes that, but rather indirectly. The fractions $\frac a\alpha=\frac b\beta=\frac c\gamma$ are all equal due to the law of sines. If you could express that fraction in terms of $R$ and $L$, then you could build on that.

Comment: @MvG Thanks for your tips. Sadly, After trying for a few hours, I still have little idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a complete rewrite of my previous post.*

Assume $\tan B=h$. Up to a similarity transformation, the corners of your triangle will have the coordinates

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\end{pmatrix}\qquad
B=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\qquad
D=\begin{pmatrix}0\\h\end{pmatrix}$$

Now assume a circle radius $r$ and you can compute the points of intersection as

$$G=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{h^{2} + \sqrt{-h^{4} + 4 \, {\left(h^{2} + 1\right)} r^{2} - 2 \, h^{2} - 1} h + 1}{2 \, {\left(h^{2} + 1\right)}} \\[2ex]
\frac{h^{3} + \sqrt{h^{2} + 1} \sqrt{-h^{2} + 4 \, r^{2} - 1} + h}{2 \, {\left(h^{2} + 1\right)}}
\end{pmatrix}\qquad
H=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -\sqrt{r^{2} - 1}\end{pmatrix}$$

Now the arc around point $B$ is

$$\frac{L_2}{R_2}=2\pi-
\arccos\frac{(G-B)\cdot(H-B)}{\lVert G-B\rVert\cdot\lVert H-B\rVert}$$

Plugging in the above coordinates, you can obtain a relation between $r$ and $\frac{L_2}{R_2}$, but that fraction is highly non-linear. Therefore it is very difficult to compute $r$ given $\frac{L_2}{R_2}$. So it should be possible to solve this numerically for a given set of numbers, but I doubt I'll be able to come up with a general closed formula for the angles.

Comment: thanks for the write-up, I will attempt this. This is a personal project of mine so it's no stress :) Have a good day!

Comment: I hope this isn't too much to ask, but when you have free time could you attempt to solve it? I am not very good at this. I am very grateful for your efforts, thanks.

Comment: @Koopa: Will be tricky. I've posted my results about as far as I get with them.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I just realize now that the problem might be a bit too abstract.

Comment: I've started to play around with the formula (plugging and the like in Wolfram Mathematica)- I have a silly question though, which part of it represents the angle G? Would it be what's inside the arccos term. Thanks for clarification

Comment: @Koopa: For the angle $G$, since $G=\pi-2B$ you have $B=\frac{\pi-G}2$ so $h=\tan B=\tan\frac{\pi-G}2$. The $G$ inside the $\arccos$ term is the *point* $G$, computed a few lines above that.